# the solution of matrix polynomials

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, algebraic-graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory, graph-laplacian

In order to get the eigenvalues of
\begin{equation}
P=\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
0_{n\times n} & I_{n\times n} \\
-A & -B%
\end{array}
\right],
\end{equation}
where $A$ and $B$ are both $n\times n$ symmetric positive semi-definite
matrices. The row sums of $A$ and $B$ are both $0$. They can be considered as
Laplacian matrices of undirected graph.

\begin{equation}
\lambda I-P=\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
\lambda I_{n\times n} & -I_{n\times n} \\
A & \lambda I_{n\times n}+B%
\end{array}
\right] ,
\end{equation}
then
\begin{equation}
\det \left( \lambda I-P\right) =\det \left( \lambda ^{2}I_{n\times
n}+\lambda B+A\right) .
\end{equation}
Suppose the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$ are respectively $0=\alpha _{1}\leq
\alpha _{2}\leq \cdots \leq \alpha _{n}$ and $0=\beta _{1}\leq \beta
_{2}\leq \cdots \leq \beta _{n}$. What is the relationship between the
eigenvalues of $P$ and the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ and $B$ commute, you can simultaneously diagonalize and the eigenvalues of $P$ will be roots of quadratics of the form $\lambda^2 +\beta_r \lambda +\alpha_r$.
If $A$ and $B$ do not commute, I fear there little that be said usefully.

Having $A$ and $B$ are symmetric and positive semidefinite does not help. Your matrix $P$ can be viewed as a block companion matrix, for whatever that is worth.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think you are right. Is it possible to get  some properties of P, such as if all the eigenvalues are not positive and number of zero eigenvalues?

Comment: The rank.of $P$ is $n$ plus the rank of $A$.